# how to compare a set of characters with a map which keys are characters?

Tags: java

If i have a set of characters which is called characters and contains the following Characters (doesn't have to be SortedSet)

```
'c''h''a''r''a''c''t''e''r'
```

and i have a map which has sets of charcters as its keys and strings as values for example

```
map<Set<Character>>,<String> aMap = new HashMap<Set<Character>>,<String>();

aMap.put('a''h''t', "hat");
aMap.put('o''g''d', "dog");
aMap.put('c''r''a''t''e', "react");
```

What javdoc method would i use to compare the characters since they are both in a Set, then to iterate through the keySet using a for loop to compare the characters to find only the keys that are made from charcters that are contained within the first. So in above example the second entry ('o''g''d', "dog") would be ommitted.

thanks

andy

Comment: Please format your question using the code formatting tools and explain the question better. What do you want to do? Can you write down some examples with the expected result?

Comment: Can you explain with more details, why should the second entry be omitted? Because it contains **no** letter from "characters", or because none of it's letters are contained in "characters"?

Comment: the second entry when compared does not have any of the same characters as the first set (ie character has no 'd', 'o' or 'g')

Answer (score 1):

To get something comparable to your set call map.keySet()

```
public class SetTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
        HashMap<Character, String> map = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        for (char c : "Character".toCharArray()) {
            set.add(c);
            map.put(c, "some value");
        }
        System.out.println( set + " == " + map.keySet() + set.containsAll( map.keySet() ));
        set.remove('C');
        System.out.println( set + " == " + map.keySet() + set.containsAll( map.keySet() ));
    }
}


[e, t, c, r, a, C, h] == [e, t, c, r, a, C, h]true
[e, t, c, r, a, h] == [e, t, c, r, a, C, h]false
```

Answer (score 0):

just play with set.containsAll(...).
example: if sets have equal sizes and firstSet.containsAll(secondSet) is true, than 2 sets are identical.

Comment: size does not matter: Returns true if this set contains all of the elements of the specified collection. If the specified collection is also a set, this method returns true if it is a subset of this set. see http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: I've talked about 2 sets being identical. If one is a subset of another and they have different sizes - there are not identical. However, maybe i misunderstood author's task.